# Can websites block selenium sendKeys() function?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver

I've been using selenium to autofill credit card information for certain websites. I use ChromeDriver and it had been working fine, but yesterday it seems like the website I had been using blocked this feature (At least I think). Here is the code I've been using. As you'll see in the code, I also tested it with FireFox and it worked just fine, so I thought it could be a ChromeDriver issue, but I've tried different versions and they all seem to have this problem on this specific website. I tried using it on google and searching something and it worked just fine with the ChromeDriver.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\WebStuff\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setHeadless(false);

    //FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    //options.setHeadless(false);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/accessories/z1fwxyqis");

    WebElement cart = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.button"));

    cart.submit();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    driver.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout");

    Thread.sleep(500);

    System.out.println("About to hit billing");

    WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.id("order_billing_name"));

    name.sendKeys("testing name");


}
```

Here is also the error I get in console

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-DOHH590', ip: '192.168.1.132', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba15..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Shayan\AppData\Loc...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 65.0.3325.181, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 26e9dd507ff523a3444484b7fedb8793
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=order_billing_name}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:319)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:365)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
    at me.iran.testing.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

Comment: I did look online and everyone that had similar problems (About a year ago) was due to the ChromeDriver bug, but I'm using the most recent one and no one else is having an issue with it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue with blocking sendKeys. I have tried to run your code in phantomjs and it works fine. I only changed the page source to http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/v2reiq8w5 since the one provided by you is not accessible.

Comment: The URL i posted seems to work for me, unless you're talking about something else. What do you suggest I should use? My friend is also having the same issue.

Comment: Same, I was able to run your code using `Java`, changed the url to: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirts/byl5txdhj. Whatever was the original problem it cannot be reproduced anymore, as the link got changed and running the code with a different link works.

Answer (score 1):

I can open the DevTools console and execute:

```
document.querySelector("#order_billing_name").value = "Kirby"
```

Which does the same thing (without using Java to actually send the keystrokes).

So, without seeing the actual error you get, here are a few guesses:

1. I am going to assume that 500ms is not a good amount of time to
   wait for the cart to load.
2. The input is data-bound so the manual act of entering text also triggers certain events ("onchange", "blur", "focus", etc).
3. You need to update Chrome and the Chrome WebDriver.

Comment: Sorry @kirbycope, let me upload the error to post.

Comment: Also to answer your other questions. 1) I tried doing it with a higher/lower waiting time in between. 2) I understand what you mean, but not sure what I should do. 3) I have the latest driver and browser.